# Nest dictionary insert to psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, dictionary, psycopg2

I am trying to input data from a nested dictionary structure into a PostgreSQL DB using psycopg2 as shown [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Psycopg2_Tutorial). What I'm unsure of is how to access the nested parts of the dictionary or if this is even possible to do in one insert query. The data structure looks like this:

```
dictionary = ({
            "article_id":94527, "article_title":"An article title",
            "country_info": [{"country_id":281133,
                              "country_code":"GB",
                              "country_name":"United Kingdom",
                              "lon":32.0000,
                              "lat":49.0000},
                             {"country_id":281133,
                              "country_code":"FR",
                              "country_name":"France",
                              "lon":22.0000,
                              "lat":39.0000}]
         })
```

And the query so far looks like this:

```
cur.execute("""
WITH article_s AS (
    SELECT id FROM article
    WHERE id = %(article_id)s
),
article_i AS (
    INSERT INTO article (article_id, article_title)
        SELECT %(article_id)s, %(article_title)s
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM article where id = %(article_id)s)
        RETURNING id
),
country_s AS (
    SELECT id FROM country
    WHERE id = %(country_id)s
),
country_i AS (
    INSERT INTO country (id, country_code, country, geom)
        SELECT %(country_id)s, %(country_code)s, %(country_name)s, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(%(lon)s, %(lat)s), 4326)
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM country_s)
        RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO article_countries (article_id, country_id)
    SELECT COALESCE (article_i.id, country_i.id),
    COALESCE (article_i.id, country_i.id)
    FROM article_i, country_i,
    article_s, country_s
;
""", dictionary)
```

Anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using postgres 9.2 or later, you can potentially convert that dictionary to json and try inserting it that way. postgres 9.2 and later has native support for a JSON type which would allow you to access nested json elements with a bit of extra sql.

[see also](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#json-adaptation)

Comment: Thank definitely looks promising, but still doesn't solve the problem of getting the nested data into the query. Could you give an example?